# How does Marshal.FreeHGlobal is freeing allocated memory?

Tags: c#, memory-management, marshalling

I am learning different ways to allocate and free memory in C#. Here is the sample code that is working.

```
   class clsA
   {
       private IntPtr _buffer;
       public clsA()
       {
            _buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
            //_buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(1024);
       }
       public void free()
       {
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_buffer);
          //Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(_buffer);
       }    
    }


   class Program
   {


      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

       unsafe
       {
            List<clsA> l = new List<clsA>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 8192; i++)
            {
                l.Add(new clsA());


            }
            Console.WriteLine("Added");
            foreach (var a in l)
            {
                a.free();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


       }
   }
```

Memory allocation is working as expected but after de-allocation 1-2 mb seems to increase after both process are done. Initially the app had 4.6 Mb. after allocation it reached to 13.3 Mb which was expected. But after freeing up that space overall app was using 7.1 Mb. What is exactly happening here? And how can I free up that remaining space.

Comment: Why are you using unsafe?  The marshal method already handles the unmanaged memory so it is safe.  To free the memory you need to set the list to null.

Comment: The allocated memory is being freed, but the Items inside the list are still there, and probably that's what is consuming the extra memory

Comment: okay. understood the unsafe context. also removed all elements from list and set it to null. But still it is same

Comment: This is pretty normal behavior for managed apps. Memory is allocated in large "chunks" that are then carved out more conservatively, and the runtime prefers not to release those chunks until garbage collection and memory pressure make it worthwhile to do so. You can use `GC.Collect()` to collect all inaccessible objects (for demonstration purposes -- do not inject such calls in production code), but this generally does not reduce the virtual memory footprint at such low numbers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried colling GC.Collect(), it did not make a difference. I took a snapshot of the memory before and after the process, apparently some objects where created internally during it and stayed after finishing

Comment: Hence "managed" code; the price you pay for having automatic memory management is that you no longer get to dictate the allocation size of the process in exact number of bytes, in return for simplified code and far less chance of allocation bugs and buffer overruns. You can use WinDbg + SOS to delve exactly into the managed heap and its segments; effectively allocated bytes can decrease while the allocated virtual memory on the OS size stays the same.